# Do Larger EBS Volumes Require more IOPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, provisioned-iops

I recently resized the root EBS volume on an EC2 instance.

I changed it from: `gp2 120GB and 360 IOPS` to: `io2 512GB and 1000 IOPS`

I was reading documentation about gp2 and they say that they give you 3 IOPS per GB which is why when I had 120 GB it had 360 IOPS.
But this made me think that IOPS per GB mattered, and now that I have 512 GB and 1000 IOPS I actually have fewer IOPS per GB than I did before. (~2 IOPS per GB as compard to 3 IOPS per GB).

So my question is, does a larger volume require more IOPS to maintain the IOPS/GB ratio? Did I actually make my EBS volume slower with these changes?

Comment: FYI you should not switch to io2 for IOPs. You get more IOPs for less cost with gp2, so it typically doesn't make sense to use io2 unless you need to either exceed 16k IOPs gp2 limit or the lower latency of io2 is important to your workload. Most other cases your generally just paying more for less.

Answer (score 2):

You switched from General Purpose (gp2) to provisioned IOPS (io2).

With gp2 you get a baseline of 100 IOPS and then 3 IOPS per GiB after the first 33.33GiB, with a max of 16,000 IOPS. Pricing is based on volume size.

> Pricing: $0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage

With io2 you provision the number of IOPS you need, independent of the volume size. io2 has a max of 64,000 IOPS. Pricing is based on volume size and the number of provisioned IOPS.

> Pricing: $0.125/GB-month + $0.065/provisioned IOPS-month

See [EBS Volume Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html) and [EBS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) for all of the details.

Unless you specifically need provisioned IOPS you probably want general purpose as it is significantly cheaper.

> Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1 and io2) volumes are designed to meet the needs of I/O-intensive workloads, particularly database workloads, that are sensitive to storage performance and consistency.

gp3 was recently released and it has a baseline of 3,000 IOPS, higher max IOPS, and is cheaper than gp2 so you may want to go with that option. It also allows you to provision additional IOPS and throughput.

As [@jordanm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) noted in the comments, gp3 may have higher latency than gp2   (both latencies are described as "single digit millisecond" in the documentation).

Comment: Note that gp3 has even higher latency than gp2, which makes it less useful for some applications.

Comment: @jordanm Why do you say this? I have seen [gp2 vs gp3 volume performance : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/maiia7/gp2_vs_gp3_volume_performance/) but that apparently was an abberation. Can you link us to some relevant information?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It could be that I am mistaken as I thought that it was officially documented, but I may have just got this info from similar user information sharing such as this one: https://silashansen.medium.com/looking-into-the-new-ebs-gp3-volumes-8eaaa8aff33e

Comment: Yeah, take the gp3 latency issue with a grain of salt. Doing some more searching I found several more user reports of higher latency with gp3, but AWS docs indicate gp3 should have similar latency to gp2